# How to scrape a website by passing a list to request for scraping each link requested

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web site by having a list which contains all the links of the website in (unspsc_list) list for different webpages but I am not able to scrape and it just prints the link on the console

```
    df_Conversion = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Ab','Unit of Measure', 'Conversion', 'Net/Gross Weight (lbs)', 'Volume (cubic ft)', 'Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H', 'GTIN']) 
    myList = ['ZOL890080401','ZOL89004004','ZOL89000180','ZOL3502111001','ZOL21110201CC','ZIM750000300','ZIM607500007','ZIM515047501','ZIM387400300','ZIM197800100','ZIM160201000','ZIM160200500','ZIG2516','ZIG1934S','ZIG1933S','ZIG1925S','XOM8229506','WTLSS1','WTLSB2','WTLRHS001','WTLOS1','WTLERSHLFM','WTLDIVAJ6','WSD909165','WOL7507040','WOL7507030','WOL7505730','WOL66084LW40','WOL66083LW40','WOL66083LW30']

    unspsc_link = []
    for i in myList:
        unspsc_link.append(f"https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP{i}")

    link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text

    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')

        SKUDATA = []
        div1 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'medSKUPriceData'})
        SKUDATA.append(div1.text.strip())

        div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'medSKUFltRt'})
        right_table3 = div.find('table', {'class': 'medSKUTableDetails table-striped uomTable'})

        df3 =  pd.read_html(str(right_table3))[0]

        df2 = pd.DataFrame(SKUDATA)
        df_ProductId = pd.DataFrame()
        df_ProductId = df_ProductId.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
        df_ProductId.columns = ['Ab']

        df_Unit_of_Measurment = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Unit of Measure', 'Conversion', 'Net/Gross Weight (lbs)', 'Volume (cubic ft)', 'Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H', 'GTIN'])
        df_Unit_of_Measurment = df_Unit_of_Measurment.append(df3, ignore_index = True)
        df_Unit_of_Measurment.columns = ['Unit of Measure', 'Conversion', 'Net/Gross Weight (lbs)', 'Volume (cubic ft)', 'Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H', 'GTIN']

        df_y = pd.DataFrame()
        df_y = pd.concat([df_ProductId,df_Unit_of_Measurment], ignore_index=True)
        df_y = df_y.fillna(method='ffill')
        df_y = df_y[1:]

        df_Conversion = df_Conversion.append(df_y, ignore_index = True)

        df_Conversion = df_Conversion[1:]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. What is the expected output and what are you currently getting?

Comment: To [_scrap_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scrap) a website equals doing a successful [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack. Please don't ;) #grammar

Comment: hey @QHarr i am trying to scrap all the link present unspsc_link that is my list  but i am not able to scrap

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to execute the loop body for all links in your list `unspsc_link`, retrieve the html for them and filter out the table inside. If that's indeed, what you want to do, you can start with the following small modifications of your code:

```
df_Conversion = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Ab','Unit of Measure', 'Conversion', 'Net/Gross Weight (lbs)', 'Volume (cubic ft)', 'Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H', 'GTIN']) 
myList = ['ZOL890080401','ZOL89004004','ZOL89000180','ZOL3502111001','ZOL21110201CC','ZIM750000300','ZIM607500007','ZIM515047501','ZIM387400300','ZIM197800100','ZIM160201000','ZIM160200500','ZIG2516','ZIG1934S','ZIG1933S','ZIG1925S','XOM8229506','WTLSS1','WTLSB2','WTLRHS001','WTLOS1','WTLERSHLFM','WTLDIVAJ6','WSD909165','WOL7507040','WOL7507030','WOL7505730','WOL66084LW40','WOL66083LW40','WOL66083LW30']

# the next line replaces your for loop
# by a list comprehension (it's just equivalent, so you can
# chooose, whatever you like more)
unspsc_link = [f"https://www.medline.com/sku/item/MDP{i}" for i in myList]
# the line link = requests.get(unspsc_link).text doesn't work I guess
# because get expects a single URL I guess

for url in unspsc_link:
    link = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')

    # the rest is actually your code, 
    # please check if it does, what you
    # want it to do with the above modifications
    # if not, maybe you can add some more infos
    # about what doesn't work and what it should
    # do
    SKUDATA = []
    div1 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'medSKUPriceData'})
    SKUDATA.append(div1.text.strip())

    div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'medSKUFltRt'})
    right_table3 = div.find('table', {'class': 'medSKUTableDetails table-striped uomTable'})

    df3 =  pd.read_html(str(right_table3))[0]

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(SKUDATA)
    df_ProductId = pd.DataFrame()
    df_ProductId = df_ProductId.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
    df_ProductId.columns = ['Ab']

    df_Unit_of_Measurment = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Unit of Measure', 'Conversion', 'Net/Gross Weight (lbs)', 'Volume (cubic ft)', 'Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H', 'GTIN'])
    df_Unit_of_Measurment = df_Unit_of_Measurment.append(df3, ignore_index = True)
    df_Unit_of_Measurment.columns = ['Unit of Measure', 'Conversion', 'Net/Gross Weight (lbs)', 'Volume (cubic ft)', 'Shipping Dimensions (inch) L x W x H', 'GTIN']

    df_y = pd.DataFrame()
    df_y = pd.concat([df_ProductId,df_Unit_of_Measurment], ignore_index=True)
    df_y = df_y.fillna(method='ffill')
    df_y = df_y[1:]

    df_Conversion = df_Conversion.append(df_y, ignore_index = True)

    df_Conversion = df_Conversion[1:]
```

Comment: just help me to print that it should print a line with number that 1 is executed for each execution

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what do you want?

Comment: like after getting the first value from the list it should print 1 is executed in console similar for others

Comment: Similar to what others? I don't see any print statemtns in your code (I mean, because you mention, something is printed in the console). The first value of which list? You mean `print(unspsc_link[0])` outside the loop or `print(url)` inside the loop? btw. you mentioned, you already changed the code, but in your post I see no update.